# Getting 502 http status code on a Service Fabric stateless service deployed on lesser node than configured VM Scaleset nodes

Tags: azure-service-fabric

We have deployed various stateless services on a 5 node cluster with **-1** as instance count as **`Singleton partition`** scheme. Recently, we decided to deploy the few stateless services only on 3 nodes out of 5 by defining instance count as 3.

After deployment, the stateless services with -1 as instance count are working and responding with HttpStatus 200 Ok. however, a stateless service deployed with 3 instance node count are intermittently responding with HttpStatus 502 with following error (from fiddler):

> The connection to 'someservername.centralus.cloudapp.azure.com' failed.
>   System.Security.SecurityException Failed to negotiate HTTPS connection with server.fiddler.network.https> HTTPS handshake to someservername.centralus.cloudapp.azure.com failed. System.IO.IOException Authentication failed because the remote party has closed the transport stream.

Below is the application manifest of deployed application for reference

```
<ApplicationManifest xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" ApplicationTypeName="MyService.ServiceFabricType" ApplicationTypeVersion="1.0.0.1.1" ManifestId="8747c387-a7fc-4b05-b189-b1c01958f066" xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/2011/01/fabric">
  <Parameters>
    <Parameter Name="My_Service_ASPNETCORE_ENVIRONMENT" DefaultValue="" />
    <Parameter Name="My_Service_InstanceCount" DefaultValue="3" />
  </Parameters>
  <ServiceManifestImport>
    <ServiceManifestRef ServiceManifestName="MyServicePkg" ServiceManifestVersion="1.0.0.1.1" />
    <ConfigOverrides />
    <EnvironmentOverrides CodePackageRef="code">
      <EnvironmentVariable Name="ASPNETCORE_ENVIRONMENT" Value="[My_Service_ASPNETCORE_ENVIRONMENT]" />
    </EnvironmentOverrides>
  </ServiceManifestImport>
  <DefaultServices>
    <Service Name="MyService" ServicePackageActivationMode="ExclusiveProcess">
      <StatelessService ServiceTypeName="MyServiceType" InstanceCount="[My_Service_InstanceCount]">
        <SingletonPartition />
      </StatelessService>
    </Service>
  </DefaultServices>
</ApplicationManifest>
```

and service manifest :

```
<ServiceManifest xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" ManifestId="59ea463b-5e4c-44f5-8982-5658b35d6c89" Name="MyServicePkg" Version="1.0.0.1.1" xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/2011/01/fabric">
  <ServiceTypes>
    <StatelessServiceType ServiceTypeName="MyService" />
  </ServiceTypes>
  <CodePackage Name="Code" Version="1.0.0.1.1">
    <EntryPoint>
      <ExeHost>
        <Program>MyService.exe</Program>
        <WorkingFolder>CodePackage</WorkingFolder>
      </ExeHost>
    </EntryPoint>
    <EnvironmentVariables>
      <EnvironmentVariable Name="ASPNETCORE_ENVIRONMENT" Value="" />
    </EnvironmentVariables>
  </CodePackage>
  <ConfigPackage Name="Config" Version="1.0.0.1.1" />
  <Resources>
    <Endpoints>
      <Endpoint Name="ServiceEndpoint" Protocol="https" Type="Input" Port="9226" />
    </Endpoints>
  </Resources>
</ServiceManifest>
```

1. Is it mandatory to deploy a stateless service all nodes in service fabric?
2. If no, how the above scenario can be configured?

Note - Currently Service Fabric is configured with Silver durability tier and with reverse proxy in **disabled** state. Also did not get any relevant solution from [this](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/application-gateway/application-gateway-troubleshooting-502) azure documentation.

Comment: I'am afraid you do not need 'Protocol="https"' even when you actually access service under http.